# Changing navbar colour in relation to it's slideDown and slideUp state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to give blue color to my navbar when the blue div which contains text is in  slideDown state - I have it. BUT when I try to give back the background image my navbar had before when it gains slideUp state it 'ignores' me. What should I improve?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('nav li a i:first').on({
          click:function(){
              $('.forperson1').slideToggle();
              var $d=$('.forperson1');
              if($d.is(':visible')) {
                  $('nav').css({
                       'background-image':'none',
                       'background-color':'blue'
                   });
              } else if($d.is(':hidden')) {
                  $('nav').css('background-image','url(https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_GB/mktg/wright/home/homepage-hero-1x.jpg)');
              };
          }
      })
  });
```

[link to my pen on Codepen](https://codepen.io/zeeebra/pen/ZJezYz)

Comment: don't change css,
1. create some class
2. Add or remove then you need
or maybe has :active stat if it is link

Comment: Why not apply a CSS class instead of setting CSS properties? Then you can just toggle the class and you don't have to worry about resetting the CSS properties to their initial value.

Comment: to your css `.scrollDown {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: none;
}` to your JS just inside the click handler `$('nav').toggleClass('scrollDown')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working CodePen:

CSS:

```
nav.open {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('nav li a i:first').on('click', function() {

    $('.forperson1').slideToggle();
    $('nav').toggleClass('open');

});

});
```

https://codepen.io/jonolayton/pen/RZyYvp